# Lebesgue integral of Dirichlet function by completion

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, complete-spaces

Let us consider the following Dirichlet function $D: [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$:
$$ D(x) = \begin{cases} 1, \quad x\in\mathbb{Q} \\ 0,\quad \mathrm{else}.\end{cases}$$

I would like to show that it is Lebesgue integrable and compute the value of the integral if I am defining it through the completion of the space of all continuous compactly supported Riemann integrable function $C_c(\mathbb{R})$, call this completion $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

As far as I understand, consider the space $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ and define its metric to be the following. If $f$ is nonzero on an interval $I_1$ and $g$ is nonzero on an interval $I_2$ then $I = I_1 \cup I_2$ is also an interval, so Riemann integral can be defined.
$$ d(f,g) = \int \limits_{I = I_1 \cup I_2} |f - g|$$

Then, define completion with respect to this metric. Before computing the value of the integral, first I have trouble understanding how to show that $D \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Each element $X \in L^1(\mathbb{R}$)  is an equivalence class $[f]$ of Cauchy sequences of $\{ f_k \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that equivalence is defined for two Cauchy sequences $\{ f_k \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, $\{ g_k \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ if and only if:
$$ \lim \limits_{k \to \infty} d(f_k, g_k) = 0 $$

I understand that if $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ then we can identify it with an element $X \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ which is equivalence class $[f]$ in which the Cauchy sequence defined by $f_k = f$ belongs to. And, intuitively, we would like to say that $D$ might be approximated by compactly supported continuous functions, but I don't see how this fits in this framework. Honestly, I don't even see how to identify arbitrary $X \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with a function in general. I guess also that from the point of view of applications, I could use identification using pointwise convergence, but I am not sure if this is what is intended.

**Question 1**: How to identify $D$ with such classes of Cauchy sequences from $C_c(\mathbb{R})$? Can you give me both general algorithm and concrete example of a Cauchy sequence for this function $D$?

Let us assume it is understood how to identify $D \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with a class of Cauchy sequences. In that case, there is supposed to be a Cauchy sequence $\{ f_k \}_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$, where for each $k$, we can define integral.

**Question 2**: Is it correct to say that the Lebesgue integral of $D$ is then defined to be the following?

$$ \int D = \lim \limits_{k \to \infty}  \int_{I_k} f_k $$

Thanks a lot, and I would really appreciate some beginner references related to this question.

Comment: $D$ is $0$-almost surely. So $D$ is integrable and $\int D=0$

Comment: Also $D(x)=\mathbb{1}){\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}(x)$. Let $\{r_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$. Then $\int D(x)\,dx =\sum_n\lambda(\{r_n\})=0$ since $\lambda(\{x\})=0$ for any $x$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks for your comment! Sorry, I could not reinterpret what you said and understand how it relates to the Cauchy sequences of compactly supported continuous functions. Can you please expand on my questions 1,2?

Comment: you are overthinking the problem. If you are starting with functions of compact support, convince yourself that for any point $x$, $\int \mathbb{1}_{\{x\}}(t)\,dt=0$ by constructing functions in $f_n\in C_c$ that converge point wise to $\mathbb{1}_{\{x\}}(t)$ and such that $\int f_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$.  Once that is done, notice the since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, say $\{r_n\}$ is an enumeration, then $\mathbb{1}_\mathbb{Q}=\lim_n\sum^n_{j=1}\mathbb{1}_{\{r_j\}}$. The rest would follow by dominated convergence.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Do I understand correctly that you claim that function $g$ is identified with the Cauchy sequence $[f]$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if $f_k \to g$ as $k \to \infty$ pointwise? Also, I don't see how you apply dominated convergence as integrals on $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ are Riemann (Darboux) integrals.

Comment: The core aspect of this question is: given this definition of $L^1$, can you give a characterization of it as (equivalence classes of) pointwise defined functions? At some level, you can: if you are familiar with Lebesgue measure and the corresponding integration theory, you can show that the Riemann-integrable functions are dense in the given norm in the (complete) space of Lebesgue-integrable functions modulo a.e. equivalence. This, however, is contingent on having access to Lebesgue measure. I do not think it's clear how to give an alternative description without something like that.

Comment: As a physicist by education, I do not think that the Dirichlet function bears any relevance in respect of applied mathematics.